# What are some books or articles that try to answer, how everyone can benefit from understanding physics in a conceptual way?

Tags: resource-recommendations, education

What are some books or articles that try to answer, how everyone can benefit from conceptual understanding of physics (meaning in a way Paul Hewitt's book Conceptual Physics teaches it)?

Answer (score 1):

If by "conceptual way" you mean without advanced mathematics & written in a readable style, the books of Isaac Asimov have a lot to recommend them. Gary Zukav is another author you could try, and there are many more. Although New Scientist and Scientific American are frowned on by the mandarins of this site, there is a lot of good stuff to be learned from them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. By "conceptual way" I meant exactly that. By my question though I do not mean that I want some sources for learning physics in a conceptual way. By my question, I meant if you know any particular sources (book, scientific study, article etc.) that try to answer the following question - What particular benefits there are for all people (who do not necessary need that knowledge in their profession) of having that conceptual knowledge of physics? For example I see things the way they really are. I think from the first principles etc.

Comment: I am trying to write an article for young people who are not particularly curious about how things work because they think it is a waste of time. In my article, I want to argument based on some other sources (scientific study etc.) that having that conceptual knowledge of physics can be very eyeopening and it can have some practical benefits in their life. In other words to motivate them to be curious about the world.

Comment: You are quite right in thinking it would be a good thing to encourage  young people to learn about science without putting them off by including higher mathematics and a textbook style of writing. It broadens the mind,exercises the brain and helps them to understand the world about them. It would be far better for young people's minds than the political correctness stuff taught in some schools today,& might encourage them to take a more academic interest & make a career of it. Young people ought to be curious,& most of them are,but this curiosity is somehow stifled as they enter their teens.